# RoR - Devise mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using rails 3.2 with ruby 1.9.3 and devise 2.1.2.

I want an admin to create users with username and email.

How can i randomly generate a password for this user, and send him an email with his password?

Answer (score 1):

First you should need create controller for handle regristration user by admin.

Assumed you name of controller is `registrations_controller.rb`

Here's `app/controller/registrations_controller.rb`

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 before_filter :resource_name

 def resource_name
  :user
 end

 def new
   @user = User.new
 end

 def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    generated_password = Devise.friendly_token.first(6) #password length 6
    @user.password_confirmation = @user.password = generated_password
    if @user.save
      # Send Password Via Email
      UserMailer.password_send(@user).deliver
      redirect_to a_path
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
 end
```

Here's `app/mailer/user_mailer.rb`

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "youremail@email.com"

   def password_send(user)
     @user = user
     mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "password", :from => "youremail@email.com")
   end
  end
```

Here's `app/views/user_mailer/password_send.html.erb`

```
   Email : @user.email<br/>
   Username : @user.username<br/>
   Password : @user.password
```

[Devise - Automatically generate password for users](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Automatically-generate-password-for-users-%28simpler-registration%29)

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

**Randomly generate a password for a user**

In your controller

```
pwd = Devise.friendly_token[0,16]

@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.password_confirmation = @user.password = pwd
```

**Send an email with his password**

Take a look at this question: [Send an actionmailer email upon user registration in devise rails 3 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668920/send-an-actionmailer-email-upon-user-registration-in-devise-rails-3-application)

In the end it will boils down to something like:

```
 mail(:to => "#{user.email}", :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site, your password #{pwd}")
```